# Execute function after another AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to execute a function which fetches data after a kind of login function who provides the `sessionId`. This `sessionId` is necessary for the second function.

```
app.controller('TestController', 
 function ($scope, dbObjectsDAO, loginService){    

    var sessionID = loginService.getSessionID(); //Login function

    var self = this;

    this.items = [];

    this.constructor = function() {
        dbObjectsDAO.getAll(sessionID).then(function(arrObjItems){
            $scope.items = arrObjItems;
        });
    };

    this.constructor(); //get the data

    return this;

});
```

I tried several variations like:

```
loginService.getSessionID().then(function(sessionID){
  this.constructor();  //also with just constructor();
});
```

But I always receive errors (in the case above: `Illegal constructor`).
So how can I manage to execute one function after another ? Maybe a callback structure would help here but I have no clue how to realize it.

---

**EDIT**
Here is the code for the login:

```
app.service('loginService', function($http, $q) {


    this.getSessionID = function()
    {
        return $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/someRequestDoneHere"
        }).then(function(response)
        {
            return response.data.sessionId; // for example rYBmh53xbVIo0yE1qdtAwg
        });
    };

    return this;

});
```

Comment: can you add the getsessionId function code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does your `getSessionID()` function return a promise? If so you want code like this:

```
app.controller('TestController', 
 function ($scope, dbObjectsDAO, loginService){    

    var sessionID;
    var vm = this;
    vm.items = [];

    loginService.getSessionID()
    .then(function(sid) {
        sessionID = sid;
        return dbObjectsDAO.getAll(sessionID);
    })
    .then(function(arrObjItems){
        vm.items = arrObjItems;
    });
 });
```

So your login service returns a promise which resolves to the session id. You can save that in a variable for use elsewhere, and also use it to trigger fetching the items.

I also changed your `self` to `vm` as that naming is an Angular convention, and stored the items in `vm.items` rather than directly in the scope.

**Edit:**
Your login code already returns a promise, not a session id. `return` inside a `then` is simply going to return a new promise that resolves to the value you are returning.

There are several ways to chain multiple `$http` requests. If they are independent of each other just fire off a bunch of requests and use `$q.all` to handle when they have all completed.

```
var promise1 = $http(something)
.then(function(response) { vm.data1 = response.data; return vm.data1; });
var promise2 = $http(something)
.then(function(response) { vm.data2 = response.data; return vm.data2; });

$q.all([promise1, promise2], function(values) {
    // here can safely use vm.data1 or values[0] as equivalent
    // and vm.data2 or values[1].
});
```

If one request depends on the result of another you could even do this:

```
var promise1 = $http(something)
.then(function(response) {
    vm.data1 = response.data;
    return { method:'GET', url: response.data.link}
 });
 var promise2 = promise1.then($http)
.then(function(response) { vm.data2 = response.data; return vm.data2; });
```

Your template needs to declare the controller using the 'controller as something' syntax:

```
<div ng-controller="TestController as test" ng-bind="test.items"></div>
```

Comment: Is it possible with your solution to chain several different `$http-requests` ? I have to deal with up to **10 different requests** which all fetch different data for a kind of dashboard.

Comment: How can I access the `vm.items` in my HTML-Template ?

Comment: @JohnDizzle I expanded my answer for you.

Comment: The "problem" is that my controller is defined in the `ng-routing-config` because my HTML is just an imported template not an actual page. I tried to use `ng-bind="TestController.items"` just before my `div` with an iterator `ng-repeat="object in items"` but without success.

Comment: @JohnDizzle Use 'ControllerAs' in your routing config. See http://willi.am/blog/2013/12/03/using-controller-as-syntax-in-angular-routes/

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to nest the second function, like this ? without the constructor call ?

```
loginService.getSessionID().then(function(sessionID){
    dbObjectsDAO.getAll(sessionID).then(function(arrObjItems){
        $scope.items = arrObjItems;
    });
});
```

Comment: While this may work it is good to avoid nested the callback functions. With promises you can chain them instead.

Comment: Yes, I do agree. Actually it might lead to the "pyramid of doom" of chain promises. My vote goes to the @Duncan answer.

Answer (score 0):

Mb you have wrong scope in

```
..then(function(sessionID){...}) ?
```

you can try some this like this:

```
var vm=this;
loginService.getSessionID().then(function(sessionID){
  vm.constructor();
});
```